# BBOX strategy to load all features?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, vector, wfs

Since I have no way, other than using BBOX strategy with my vector layer + wfs protocol 
[Is it required to use BBOX strategy with WFS protocol in OpenLayers 2?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35142/is-it-required-to-use-bbox-strategy-with-wfs-protocol-in-openlayers/35204#35204)

I'm wondering if there is a way to force BBOX to load all layer features, not just display data that is within the map's extent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should use [OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/devdocs/files/OpenLayers/Strategy/Fixed-js.html) strategy instead BBOX.

Comment: I should, but this is not working for me !! take a look here please http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35142/is-it-required-to-use-bbox-strategy-with-wfs-protocol-in-openlayers/35204#35204

Comment: Have you tried it with WFS protocol in vector layer ?